# Using Zend_Dom as a screen scraper

Tags: php, zend-framework, screen-scraping

How?

More to the point...

this:

```
$url = 'http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php';
$client = new Zend_Http_Client($url);
$response = $client->request();
$html = $response->getBody();
$dom = new Zend_Dom_Query($html);
$result = $dom->query('div.note');
Zend_Debug::dump($result);
```

gives me this:

```
object(Zend_Dom_Query_Result)#867 (7) {
  ["_count":protected] => NULL
  ["_cssQuery":protected] => string(8) "div.note"
  ["_document":protected] => object(DOMDocument)#79 (0) {
  }
  ["_nodeList":protected] => object(DOMNodeList)#864 (0) {
  }
  ["_position":protected] => int(0)
  ["_xpath":protected] => NULL
  ["_xpathQuery":protected] => string(33) "//div[contains(@class, ' note ')]"
}
```

And I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do anything with this.

I want to extract the various parts of the retrieved data (that being the div with the class "note" and any of the elements inside it... like the text and urls) but cannot get anything working.

Someone pointed me to the DOMElement class over at php.net but when I try using some of the methods mentioned, I can't get things to work. How would I grab a chunk of html from a page and go through it grabbing the various parts? How do I inspect this object I am getting back so I can at least figure out what is in it?

Hjälp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Iterator` implementation of `Zend_Dom_Query_Result` returns a `DOMElement` object for each iteration:

```
foreach ($result as $element) {
    var_dump($element instanceof DOMElement); // always true
}
```

From the *$element* variable, you can use any [DOMElement](http://php.net/DOMElement) method:

```
foreach ($result as $element) {
    echo 'Element Id: '.$element->getAttribute('id').PHP_EOL;
    if ($element->hasChildNodes()) {
        echo 'Element has child nodes'.PHP_EOL;
    }
    $aNodes = $element->getElementsByTagName('a');
    // etc
}
```

You can also access the [document element](http://php.net/DOMDocument), or you can use `Zend_Dom_Query_Result` to do so:

```
$document1 = $element->ownerDocument;
$document2 = $result->getDocument();
var_dump($document1 === $document2); // true
echo $document1->saveHTML();
```

Comment: This was the direction I needed. Now I'm working with results fine. Thanks so much for the explanation and pointers.